# CSS/SCSS Modules not unique classnames

Tags: next.js, sass, next.js13, css-modules

Is there a way to prevent CSS Modules in NextJS from creating unique classnames? I have tried the suggested solutions and config options from https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader, and https://github.com/mattcarlotta/next-sass-localidentname/blob/master/next.config.js, but on Next 13 nothing is seeming to work. I'm not sure why css modules is turning classnames unique, we shouldn't need them to be. If a unique identifier is needed, you would use IDs.

If I write an element, like an H5 with className="test", the className just doesn't show up at all in the web inspector. It's not until i write it as className={styles.test}, AND add .test {} in the .scss file that a style will be applied and the classname shows up in the inspector, but then the className is hashed and appears as "footer_test__09fuk"

Comment: Change the extension from `.module.css` to just `.css`? Isn't unique class names the only reason you create css modules?

Comment: Yeah that did work just fine. Obviously solution, thanks!!